# Bug(?): incorrect answer count

Tags: bug, status-deferred

[In this Q&A at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164038/monitor-vs-mutex-in-c) there are (at the time of writing this) 3, answers, while the text above the answers says (2 answers). The answers were all posted more than 15 minutes ago. (I have a screen shot, but can't upload it anywhere until I get home after work).

I have experienced this a couple of times before. Doesn't really matter a great deal for me, I can handle the situation, but felt that I'd better report it anyway.

Comment: Did you reach home? Do you have the screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

typically, this is because authors delete / undelete their answers. That doesn't appear true in this case, which is odd -- although all three responses were posted in the same second, so maybe a collision in the database field increment?

At any rate, answer count is denormalized and gets updated daily by a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another case: [C# Style XML Comments in Delphi 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408393/c-style-xml-comments-in-delphi-2010). It has now 1 answer, but it does not say 1 Answer. Maybe better noticeable from the [Delphi tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi). It shows red with zero answers.

And I doubt the question was asked and the answer given in the same second :)

**edit:** Or should I post a new question for the stackoverflow team to notice this new case?

Comment: Your answer bumped the post to the first page so it might get noticed again.