# Why does this question have 1 answer but it doesn't show as such?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

when you go to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/48664/why-is-sql-server-2005-hanging-up-when-i-try-to-delete-a-database), there's an answer already

but before you click that, it says "0 answers" - or is that supposed to be that way?

here's what it looks like before you click on it:

[image]

but when you click on the question, there's already ONE answer!

[image]

Comment: Duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8058/bug-incorrect-answer-count

Comment: @Ian with pictures also? :P

Answer (score 3):

The homepage on all the sites are cached. Jeff confirmed this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/potential-bug-see-who-voted-last)

Comment: They are cached every minute. But that was answered 7 minutes ago. Odd.

Comment: Nevermind, the first screen shot was taken 6 minutes before the second, meaning that it wouldn't show up on the home page.

Comment: wow. Jeff actually edited my question! :)