# Question clearly has 4 answers but StackOverflow labels it 3!

Tags: bug, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bug(?): incorrect answer count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8058/bug-incorrect-answer-count)

I think its a bug, clearly there are four answers all with 1+ rep, but it displays 3 answers.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940177/make-a-textarea-all-caps/4940190#4940190)

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Short answer: known issue; probably due to database contention; the count is corrected by a daily script.

Comment: i thought my eyes were playing tricks on me

Comment: The daily script has now run, and it correctly shows 4 answers.