# Why can't I see the answer to one of my questions?

Tags: support, questions, answers

I asked a question on Stack Overflow.

I was really interested in this question, but after more than one month I still hadn't got a reply. However, finally today I read in the question details "1 Answer", I was so happy, but when I clicked to read the answer, it was not there.

Why is that? Was it erased or something by someone? How come it says 1 answer, but there is no answer at all. Is it a bug?

Here, see for yourselves: [How to place markers on google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840802/how-to-place-markers-on-google-map?answertab=votes#tab-top)

**Update**

I just went to the profile of the person that it says answered my question, https://stackoverflow.com/users/27615/razlebe#qpage_1-anpage_3-qsort_views-ansort_newest, but I don't see the title of my question in his answers. Why is that? Now I am really confused.

This is no good, because my question now is not well positioned in the Stack Overflow results. Why is this happening?

Comment: It was spam apparently and was deleted.  I probably would have voted to undelete it if it was valid or at least share it with you here, but since it isn't, it's too bad.  Sorry.  p.s., the person you linked to tried to clean up the post prior to it's removal.  So he really didn't answer, just did janitorial work.

Comment: I understand. But this looks like a bug to me. If in anyway the answers are deleted, the counters should go down by 1. I made an update as Vinnet said in the answer to ask them reset my answer counter, i hope it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The answer count on the home and question pages is cached and it will get reset back to 0 at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just looked at the answer posted (via moderator tools). The answer was deleted sometime back, and was(?) spam; it was downvoted thrice. You don't really have to worry about losing any answers in this case.

Comment: Ok so that was the reason. Is there anyway for the question to say again 0 ansers? When it already has an answer the question now does not appear in the first page of the results, so is more difficult to get an answer.

Comment: Going by [Jeff's answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8058/bug-incorrect-answer-count), it will be reset when the daily job runs. You might want to edit your question to ask this specifically.

Comment: So i should edit the question asking to the moderator to erase the point from one answer right?

Comment: I don't think mods can do that. You could ask if the answer count gets reset.

Comment: I edited the question and added that request as you said. Thanks for your help. I hope it works :)

Comment: Uh, I guess I should have been more specific. I was referring to updating this question on meta, in case you wanted a more specific answer on the daily answer count reset.