# Question answer count is incorrect due to caching?

Tags: support, caching, answer-count

18 hours ago one of my questions had an activity via Community User. Seems It removed some spam answer or something. Now even after 18 hours, it's showing 3 answers on the list of questions and only 2 answers on question page.

Please see the screenshot below. My [Profile Url](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179855/mohit-jain) and [Question url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871751/how-to-download-youtube-videos-in-ruby-on-rails).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your profile page is showing cached answer count data. A moderator deleted a spammer's account, and along with it all of his answers, about a day ago, a few hours after the spammer posted a non-answer to your question.

According to [Jeff's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8058/bug-incorrect-answer-count/8059#8059) (if I interpret it right), the count will be corrected by a job run once a day.